# Java - How Can I Check If A Class Is Inheriting From Some Class Or Interface?

Tags: java, reflection, instances

I need to check:

```
public static boolean check(Class<?> c, Class<?> d)
{
    if (/* c inherits from d */)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

**How can I do that ?**

And is that possible without `c.newInstance()` ?

---

The title was wrong at the first time. Now it's correct.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use `isAssignableFrom`

```
if(d.isAssignableFrom(c)){
    // then d is a superclass of c
    // in other words, c inherits d
}
```

> Determines if the class or interface represented by this Class object
>   is either the same as, or is a superclass or superinterface of, the
>   class or interface represented by the specified Class parameter. It
>   returns true if so; otherwise it returns false. If this Class object
>   represents a primitive type, this method returns true if the specified
>   Class parameter is exactly this Class object; otherwise it returns
>   false.

[Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29)

Answer (score 3):

There is a method called [**Class#isInterface()**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInterface%28%29) in **[Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html)**

```
 if (c.isInterface())
            return true;
```

Comment: I didn't downvote but my first thought when I saw this answer was how does it check for inheritance or an implementation of a specific interface.  Maybe the question changed on you, but if you reread it, the OP is looking to discover if one class extends another or implements a specific interface.  Notice the `c inherits d` comment?

Comment: @KevinBowersox initially question title was different. :)

Comment: Thats what I suspected, your usually on point with good answers.

Comment: Down voting in not fair if question is changed after answer is posted !

Comment: @Apurv actually, its not the matter of the downvote.its just that the downvoter should leave a comment mentioning his reason . :)

Comment: @PermGenError I guess sometimes people show too much rush while evaluating an answer !

Answer (score 2):

Try this out

```
if(c.isAssignableFrom(d)){
   return true;
} else {
   return false;
}
```

Comment: Right hint but c and d must be exchanged `d.isAssignableFrom(c)`.

Comment: wouldn't it make more sense to write return c.isAssignableFrom(d)? Or are you Mr Verbose

Answer (score 1):

How about

[`public boolean isInterface();`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInterface%28%29)

According to docs:

> Determines if the specified Class object represents an interface type.
>   Returns:
>           true if this object represents an interface; false otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (c.isInterface()) return true;
```

isInterface

```
public boolean isInterface()
```

Determines if the specified Class object represents an interface type.
Returns:
true if this object represents an interface; false otherwise.
sAssignableFrom

```
public boolean isAssignableFrom(Class<?> cls)
```

Determines if the class or interface represented by this Class object is either the same as, or is a superclass or superinterface of, the class or interface represented by the specified Class parameter. It returns true if so; otherwise it returns false.
If this Class object represents a primitive type, this method returns true if the specified Class parameter is exactly this Class object; otherwise it returns false.

Specifically, this method tests whether the type represented by the specified Class parameter can be converted to the type represented by this Class object via an identity conversion or via a widening reference conversion.
 See The Java Language Specification, sections 5.1.1 and 5.1.4 , for details.

Parameters:
cls - the Class object to be checked
Returns:
the boolean value indicating whether objects of the type cls can be assigned to objects of this class
Throws:
NullPointerException - if the specified Class parameter is null.
Since:
JDK1.1

Answer (score 0):

have you tried with

```
c.isInterface()???
```

from docs

> Determines if the specified Class object represents an interface type.